# I created 2 UK immigration accounts

Tags: uk, paperwork, applications, uk-residents

I renewed my passport and I was trying to update it on gov.uk but accidently I created a new pre settlement application, I didn't finish it and just cancelled the application, but the account remains and it has my passport, now when I try to update my actual account with the new passport it says the passport is already in the system. This isn't to big of a problem since I'm about to just change it to my ID card, I can still use it since I have pre settlement status.

But is there any way to change it to my new passport?

Comment: Did you try contacting [Home office](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/home-office)?

Comment: Should I? Is there a possibility I did something illegal?

Comment: No, just to update your details the easiest way to do it is through the normal way by contacting the home office and tell them that what you say here.